# How to convert date with time in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with type DATE. How do i convert the below date to be able to insert it into the table.

```
15-JUL-12  3:09pm
```

I tried the following, but it keeps saying Incorrect date time values.

```
STR_TO_DATE('15-JUL-12  3:09pm', '%d-%m-%y %h:%i%p')
```

Comment: Use the `str_to_date()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STR_TO_DATE() is the correct function to use, but there is a problem with the format string.

Use %b for abbreviated month name (or generally %M for month names) in your format string. E.g.:

```
STR_TO_DATE('15-JUL-12  3:09pm', '%d-%b-%y %h:%i%p')
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format
for documentation of format symbols